# Passing Multiple JSON parameters in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

My registration form is accepting body in JSON format, and I need to run the test with 5 different user names.

How do I pass JSON as request body? Also I was unable to pass parameter from CSV file. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan
2. Configure it like:

   - Filename: `full path to the file with your emails`
   - Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `EmailId`

     [image: JMeter CSV Data Set]
3. In your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler copy the recorded value to Body Data" tab and replace hard-coded email with JMeter Variable like:

   ```
   {"EmailId" : "${EmailId}"}
   ```

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request with Variable]
4. In [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) set "Number of Threads" to `5`

   [image: JMeter Number of Threads]

Next time you run your test JMeter will read next line from the `file.csv` and substitute the `${EmailId}` variable with the value from the CSV file.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for more information on parameterising your JMeter tests via CSV files.